# Writing in json format as an array of json object in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

Currently I am using this to write output in single partition.

```
 df.coalesce(1).write
.format("json")
.mode("overwrite")
.option("path",writePath)
.save
```

Ouput file is currently in this format :

{obj1}
{obj2}

I want this as an array of json object.
[{obj1},
{obj2}]

Answer (score 0):

Spark infers and writes json files where each line is a separate, self-contained valid JSON object.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html

However for your desired output,

```
df.toJSON.collect.mkString("[", "," , "]" )
```

Note that `collect` on large dataframes is not recommended. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37368986/5394031)

Comment: thanks, but not able to use 
df.write method after using above function

Comment: Obviously, df.write wont work. I made it a string.
As per Spark, each row is an independent JSON object.
If you want to use df write then just collect the df -> make String -> Convert to a df of single row single column -> use df.write